# principal not being propagated when authenticating on JBoss EAP 6.3 using DatabaseServerLoginModule

Tags: authentication, jboss, principal

I am extremely new to doing JBoss deployments and I just inherited the task of migrating our RAP web-app and our Seam based web-app from JBoss 7.1.1 to EAP 6.3. The seam based web app is up and running fine, but I cannot get past the authentication portion on the RAP/Faces side. The logs show the user is being authenticated correctly, but the principal name is anonymous and it appears the EJBContext is not retaining the authenticated user principal information after being authenticated.

I have the login-module defined as so:

```
<security-domain name="myRealm" cache-type="default">
  <authentication>
     <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule"
        flag="sufficient">
          <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
          <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
          <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/myDatasource"/>
          <module-option name="principalsQuery" 
            value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM USER WHERE USER_NAME = ?"/>
          <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT VALUE, 'Roles'
            from ROLES where USER_NAME = ?"/>
    </login-module>
    ...
    </authorization>
</security-domain>
```

my jboss-web.xml is thus:

```
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>java:/jaas/myRealm</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

As I mentioned, the authentication appears to be working fine as the logs indicate the correct roles come from the DB and no constraints are indicated. However this information is not being propagated/retained in the principal...so when the RAP application entry point is hit, and the EJBContext is accessed to do our work and create the UI, it fails.

I assume it is something that I am not doing in this migration, but thus far the help I have found in this area has not helped me get past this roadblock. We are using on older version of RAP (1.2 I believe). In this migration we are also moving to Java 8, but my issue happens using Java 7 as well (which we used for our JBoss 7.1.1 impl). So I am "assuming" it is not a Java issue, but an EAP deployment issue. And since we are using the default DatabaseServerLoginModule module, I have not defined my own login module like I would potentially if I was extending the one that comes with 6.3.

...some updated information that may help anyone looking to step in and help on this. In the standalone-full.xml file I specify the "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" module, but in the trace logs is seems that entries are coming from "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.DatabaseServerLoginModule." I do not know if this is correct or is an issue. The trace logs from my 7.1.1 impl show all entries coming from the module specified in the standalone-full.xml file and not the catalina version.

I also see that for the 7.1.1 impl I have the log entry "User 'user' authenticated, loginOk=true" but for the EAP I never see the loginOk flag being set even though the module seems to indicate the user authenticated by saying "Authenticated 'user' with type 'FORM'" and "User [user] has role [User]." But the EAP login module does not seem to be setting the loginOk flag=true like it should be. As such, from what I have found, the Principal is not updated with the user's information as it should be doing.

If I assume the module "org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" as defined still works, then maybe there is an issue in the "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.DatabaseServerLoginModule" module being used as a proxy or wrapper to the JBoss module whereby it is not setting the loginOk flag which would in turn have the correct Principal values set. But that is speculation on my part.

Comment: How does you implement the login in the web application?

Comment: we are using a login.jsp defined in the web.xml like this:  
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <realm-name>myRealm</realm-name>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/unauthenticated.jsp</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>

our implementation worked under JBoss 7.1.1 and Java 7. plz let me know if my response did not address/answer your question